SublimeText How do I make the custom syntax do some basic things?
I'm trying to create my own syntax definition for plaintext files.
I'm probably doing this in a very hacky way, but it seems to work ok. How do I find more "colours" like:
keyword.control.c
string.quoted.double.c
constant.numeric.c

As I would like just sprinkle more colour in my text files... mainly a red and a blue.

I am using a
Plain Text Coloured.sublime-syntax

and it looks like this:
%YAML 1.2

---

# http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html

name: Plain Text Coloured

file_extensions: [txt]

scope: source.txt

contexts:
  
  main: 
    # Purple
    - match: (MONDAY|TUESDAY|WEDNESDAY|THURSDAY|FRIDAY|SATURDAY|SUNDAY|CODEX|SORTIUM|LEXICANUM|GAWK|PCB NONSOMNUS|NONSOMNUS|MUTIM|PCB MUTIM|MUTIM|AQOS)
      scope: keyword.control.c

    # Green
    - match: '=='
      scope: string.quoted.double.c
    - match: '--'
      scope: string.quoted.double.
    - match: ':'
      scope: string.quoted.double.c
    - match: '✔'
      scope: string.quoted.double.c
    - match: '→'
      scope: string.quoted.double.c
    - match: '←'
      scope: string.quoted.double.c
    - match: '↑'
      scope: string.quoted.double.c
    - match: '↓'
      scope: string.quoted.double.c
    - match: '|'
      scope: string.quoted.double.c

      # Orange
    - match: '~'
      scope: constant.numeric.c 
    - match: '✗'
      scope: constant.numeric.c 
    - match: '>='
      scope: constant.numeric.c 
    - match: '<='
      scope: constant.numeric.c 
    - match: '>'
      scope: constant.numeric.c 
    - match: '<'
      scope: constant.numeric.c 
    - match: '±'
      scope: constant.numeric.c 
    
      # Red highlight
      # scope: constant.character.escape.c
    
    # - match: '..'
      # scope: constant.other.markdown
      # scope: keyword.txt
      # scope: comment.txt
      # Potential lexicanum :: Morphims | Alchemy | Necromancy  | Conjure | Exorcisim | Rune


I've tried looking around for syntax definition of C for sublime but cannot find anything, is that even the right search query?

Syntax definitions in Sublime provide semantic information about the text; the colors are actually applied by your color scheme.
For example, your syntax example contains this:
    - match: '~'
      scope: constant.numeric.c 

That is telling the syntax system that it should apply the semantic scope of constant.numeric.c to any ~ that it happens to see. The name that is used here is entirely free form and up to the author of the syntax definition (in this case you).
What is causing that to appear orange in your file is this part of your color scheme (example here is Mariana):
        {
            "name": "Number",
            "scope": "constant.numeric",
            "foreground": "var(orange)"
        },

Here the color scheme rule says that anything that has a semantic scope that matches constant.numeric should appear as whatever color is defined in the variable named orange.
As I mentioned above, the scope that is applied by a syntax definition is entirely open; you can use whatever name you want for things. However in order for things that match it to appear as a specific color, the color scheme has to have a rule like the one above that tells Sublime what color to use when it encounters one.
Generally speaking, there is a set of names that are used for things (in your example, numbers) that are used for all syntax definitions so that a single color scheme can apply the correct color no matter what the language used is.
So for example C, C++, Python, Java would all display their numbers as orange, allowing you as the person editing files to recognize things easier.
(Side note: note that the scope in your example is constant.numeric.c but the color scheme just matches constant.numeric ; this allows you to have color scheme rules that are more specific for certain purposes, such as if you strongly desire Orange numbers everywhere but Java, where you want them to be purple. In which case you could have a color scheme rule that matches only numbers in java).
Based on this, you have a couple of options available to you to do what you want:

You can continue the way you're going above; if you want to have other colors, find something in some source file that is the color that you want, and use Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name to see what names are applied to it, and then use that name in your syntax.

You can apply names that make more semantic "sense" for what it is you're trying to do in your syntax, and then add rules to your color scheme that applies the color you want.


The advantage to #1 is that it's easier to do; someone has already set up the color scheme, so you just need to make your syntax do what some other syntax is doing. The down side is that you are limited only to the colors that are commonly used in color schemes.
The advantage to #2 is that you have full control over the colors you want, at the expense of having to do more work.
Here's a simple example; with a syntax rule like this:
    - match: '~'
      scope: custom.orange

Select UI: Customize Color Scheme from the command palette, and in the rules section of the file that appears in the right hand side, add:
        {
            "name": "Custom text that is orange",
            "scope": "custom.orange",
            "foreground": "var(orange)"
        },

Now the text should be the color it was, but you can:

Modify the foreground, say to confusingly make things blue:
        "foreground": "var(blue6)"


Add a background to call attention to it
        "background": "var(black)"


Include font_style to make the text, bold, italic, underline, glow, or some combination of all three:
        "font_style": "bold italic underline glow"




As a side note, you may want to change the scope at the top of the syntax to something like:
scope: text.plain.custom

Various mechanisms in Sublime infer whether the current file is source code or plain text based on how the scope starts; a scope of source.text makes it think it's a source code file. So things like the lorem snippet that normally work in regular text files won't work here.
However, this may be your intent, in which case never mind. :)
